# how to ensure that a variable value does not change at the runtime in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

suppose i have a web page with PHP and HTML CSS JavaScript.
values in database are inserted through PHP.
cookies are set using PHP.
cookies are fetched using JavaScript.
[cookies of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhs9c.png)
i have an array of subjects stored in cookies. cookies also contain index varible with initial value 0. and arraySize varible with value 9.

At the very first time i fetch the first subject
and take some form response from the user associated to that subject using POST method . when the user click the submit button . the index variable is incrementing at runtime and next subject(next value of array) is inserted in the database.
that is when user clicks the submit button , my code is first updating the subject and then insert the form data into the database.

suppose i have a subject array : subject = {'a' , 'b' , 'c'};
let form variables be subject , class .
i fill the form for subject 'a' and when click the submit button subject inserted is 'b' and class inserted is what user write.

the following JavaScript i have written for incrementing the subject(i increment the index of subject) after submitting the form :
(let say it code1.)

```
  <script>

function  incrementCookie() {
var i = document.cookie.indexOf('index');
let currentIndexValue = document.cookie[i + 6] -'0';
document.cookie='index='+(++currentIndexValue);
} 
incrementCookie();
</script>
```

code2: (inserting form variables into the database)

```
if (isset($_POST['insert']))
   {
                
                
    $co1 = $_POST['co1'];
    $co2 = $_POST['co2'];
    $co3 = $_POST['co3'];
    $co4 = $_POST['co4'];
    $co5 = $_POST['co5'];
    if($GLOBALS['cols'] == 6)
    $co6 = $_POST['co6'];
    else
    $co6 = 0;
    echo "aayush";
    $sb1 = $_POST['sb1'];
    $sb2 = $_POST['sb2'];
    $sb3 = $_POST['sb3'];
    $sb4 = $_POST['sb4'];
    $sb5 = $_POST['sb5'];
    $id1 = $_SESSION['id'];
    $sub = $_POST['subject'];
    $uname = mysqli_query($con,"select email from users where id = $id1");
                $result1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($uname);
                $usersemail = $result1['email'];
             
                $sql1 = "select email from faculty where subjectalloted = '$sub1' and section = (select section from users where id= '$id1')";
                $result2= mysqli_query($con , $sql1);
                $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
                $facultyemail = $row1['email'];
  co1='$co1',co2='$co2',co3='$co3',co4='$co4',co5='$co5',co6='$co6',sb1='$sb1',sb2='$sb2',sb3='$sb3',sb4='$sb4',sb5='$sb5' where id= (select max(id) from respone)");
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `respone` (`subject`,`usersemail`,`facultyemail`, `co1`, `co2`, `co3`, `co4`, `co5`, `co6`, `sb1`, `sb2`, `sb3`, `sb4`, `sb5`) VALUES ('$sub1', '$usersemail', '$facultyemail','$co1', '$co2', '$co3', '$co4', '$co5', '$co6', '$sb1', '$sb2', '$sb3', '$sb4', '$sb5')";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    
  }
```

code3: (fetching the subject)

```
$data = json_decode($_COOKIE['subjectArrayCookie'], true);
$index = $_COOKIE['index'];
global $sub;
$sub = $data[$index];
 $_POST['subject'] = $sub;
```

i have tried writing code2 before code1 so that form responses inserted into database first and then
index cookie update. but due to dynamic nature of JavaScript it increments the index cookie and
subject is updated to next subject before inserting the form variables into the database.

i am expecting that,  when the user clicks the submit button firstly  form data for that subject will insert into the database with their correct subject name and after then same form will open for next subject in the array.

Comment: Is you're PHP and Javascript all on one page? Are you using [Fetch](https://javascript.info/fetch) or [XHR (Ajax)](https://javascript.info/xmlhttprequest) to get the next subject? Or a page reload?

Comment: yes , i am using all the written code above on the same page . first i have fetched the subject array from the database and then insert into the cookie . with other cookies variables like index and araysize.
after that i created the form with the submit button then wrote the code2(inserting into database) and then code1(iincrement index cookie). but when i click the submit button it first updating the subject then insert into database . after that new page comes with that updated subject content.

Comment: one more thing i have not Fetch and XHR(Ajax) . Are these use to compromise with that stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

Put your PHP database insertion code at the very top of the file—before everything else, particularly the database query. Allow it to execute first.

Here's why...

---

> all the written code above on the same page.

And from comments:

1. first i have fetched the subject array from the database
2. then insert into the cookie
3. after that i created the form with the submit button
4. then wrote the code2(inserting into database)
5. then code1(iincrement index cookie).

All the PHP in the entire file is executed on the server BEFORE any Javascript is executed or HTML rendered.

The result of PHP execution creates a text file containing—ONLY—HTML and Javascript. This text file is sent to the browser. NO PHP is sent to the browser therefore NONE of the PHP is executed in the browser. Only HTML is rendered and Javascript is executed in the browser.

So the order of execution, according to the 1-5 sequence above, is:

ON THE SERVER:

1. PHP gets data from the database and writes the cookie instructions. (The cookie not yet registered in the browser.)
2. PHP writes the form HTML code to be sent to the browser. (The HTML is not yet rendered in the browser.)
3. Upon initial requests of the page `if (isset($_POST['insert']))` is NOT executed since there is no `$_POST` array yet. *However,* when this file is requested by posting form data to it PHP inserts the posted data into the database.
4. The Javascript code block text is added to the text file to be sent to the browser. (Javascript is NOT executed here.)
5. The text file containing cookie instructions, form HTML, and Javascript cookie increment code is sent to the browser.

IN THE BROWSER:

1. The cookie, written in SERVER step 1, is registered.
2. The form HTML is rendered.
3. The Javascript cookie code is executed and increments the cookie.